# Hibernate QueryBuilder how to mimic 'like' query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search, query-builder, sql-like

I am learning this API now. I have some code as below, but it does an exact match instead of a 'like'. So when I have a String `JMeter`, and I use `Meter`, it does not bring it back in the search result but it should. Any help greatly appreciated

```
SearchManager searchManager = Search.getSearchManager(listingIndex);

 QueryBuilder qb = searchManager.buildQueryBuilderForClass(ListingIndexEntry.class).get();

Query q = qb.keyword().onField("title").matching(title).createQuery();
```

Thank you

Karthik

Comment: What Hibernate version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hibernate search then I think you are looking for wildcard queries.

Check the documentation about it [there](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#search-query-querydsl) section 5.1.2.3

So your code will become :

```
Query q = qb.keyword().wildcard().onField("title").matching("*"+title).createQuery();
```

Watchout for the performance as specified in the documentation, starting with a wildcard is not very good.

Comment: I tried this (q = qb.keyword().wildcard().onField("title").matching("JMete*").createQuery();) but now it does not even return results on JMeter! ANything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Wildcard queries do not apply the analyzer on the matching terms. So assuming that you lower case the terms you need to use "jmete*" See also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl