# Hibernate search - '%like%' type query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate-search in my Spring MVC project and I would like to accomplish something but I'm not sure if it's possible. Here is the problem:

I'm using **NGramFilterFactoryClass** for this and have configured **minGramSize=3** and **maxGramSize=3**.

Let's say my search term is "*Keyword*"

If I type anything like this:

```
"ywo", "key", "ord", "blablaordblabla"
```

query will return "Keyword". This is fine and I understand how this works but what I wanna do is when I type something like:

```
"bkey", "blablaordblabla"
```

I don't want to return "Keyword". "Keyword" should be returned only when search term is something like:

```
"key", "ord", "ywo", "eywo", "word" etc...
```

So, I guess I'm looking for a '%like%' type query. How can I accomplish this with hinernate-search?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if is what you are looking for, but maybe you need what is called "wildcard queries".

Try to have a look at [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#search-query-querydsl) as reference.
Also have a look at [this stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344896/hibernate-querybuilder-how-to-mimic-like-query)

Answer (score 1):

If you Analyze your input with NGrams you won't be able to perform exact "Like%" queries.
You probably want a *SimpleAnalyzer* or something similar which doesn't completely break your keywords in smaller pieces, or you might want to skip Analysis for this field and index it as-is.

You then combine this with a WildCard Query; note how [example in the reference docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html#search-query-querydsl)  uses the *keyword* element to build the query, which inherently disables the analyzer on the input. (Make sure you scroll down the the *Wildcard queries* section in the docs).

I assume you're using NGrams because you need them for another use case. Remember you can use the @Fields annotation to index a same property in various different ways, so you could index it with ngrams and also in another form more suited for wildcard queries.